# Nodejs - Express JSON parser cannot respond back

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, node.js, parsing

My problem: once I submit a JSON object with JQuery to my express app which uses JSON parser(belongs to the module body-parser) and try to respond back to it, be it res.send or res.render, it does nothing. I try to output html directly back to the client as an html response.
On the other hand, on the same page of my website, I tried the regular body parser and the response works fine. 
Here is my JSON listener:

controller.js:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:
false }); 

app.post('/video', jsonParser, function(req, res) {
res.send("hi"); //nothing happens

console.log(req.body.time); //works, i get the data
console.log(req.body.src); //works, i get the data
});
```

the form that submits to it:

index.html

```
...mywebsite code, uses jquery
fu();

function fu(){
    var vid = document.getElementById("vid");
    var time = vid.currentTime;
    var src = vid.currentSrc;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/video",
        data: JSON.stringify({time: time, src: src  }), //the data is parsed fine
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    });

    //alert("current time: " + time);
};
```

---

Now, I have tried a simple form with a body parser and it works fine, on the exact same website(I put it there just to see if it will work):

controller.js

```
 var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended:
false }); 

app.post('/person', urlencodedParser, function(req, res){
    res.send('Thanks!');
    console.log(req.body.firstname);
    console.log(req.body.lastname);    
});
```

the person form:

```
      <form method="POST" action="/person">
        Firstname: <input type ="text" id="firstname"
        name="firstname"><br>
        Lastname: <input type ="text" id="lastname"
        name="lastname">
        <input type="submit" value="sumbit">
    </form>
```

Comment: You don't have to `stringify` data you send to server. Try: `data: {time: time, src: src  }` instead.

Comment: it doesn't work without stringify, I just tried...

Comment: I does work perfectly. At least if you arrange your server as me: https://gist.github.com/Nonemoticoner/366c02f7db613566d3cf

Comment: You wrote `dataType: 'json'` but you send plain text in response. Also, catching the response to any variable would be useful I believe. Currently your AJAX request does nothing with it.

Comment: ok, I tried your example without the stringify, it works. i can see the data on the console. though, there is still no response. the "hi" won't show up.

Comment: To make myself clear: I want the "hi" response to appear directly on the browser, as html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the response in the client after `$.ajax` request. Set `done` function to handle success callback:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/video",
        data: {time: time, src: src  },
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json'
    })
    .done(function( data, status, xhttp) {
         // put the data in the DOM 
         document.getElementById("hi").text(data);
    });
```

Comment: so that's how ajax works, ok. is there any other way that it won't go directly into success? just for common knowledge.

Comment: sure, you can handle others options such as: `error`, `complete`. Take a look to this: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Comment: no, i mean - just render the entire page that you want to send back and send it as a whole as the response, don't send it all as a string into that function that belongs to ajax and then decide what to do with it

Comment: Well AJAX is mean to do exactly that, send something without the need to render the entire page. If you want to render the entire page, just make an HTTP request to the server and respond with a view back.

Answer (score 0):

Hm, looks pretty easy - you are not using `jsonParser` in the second snippet - just `urlencodedParser`, which is not correct here. So it should looks like here:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }); 

app.post('/person', jsonParser, function(req, res){
    res.send('Thanks!');
    console.log(req.body.firstname);
    console.log(req.body.lastname);    
});
```

Comment: No, my problem is with the 1st example. everything after "Now, I have tried a simple form with a body..." is my 2nd example. and btw the 2nd example works fine as it is, no need to use the json parser.

Comment: Ok, so I don't understand what do you mean by that `send` method does nothing, did you mean a no response is given or nothing happens in browser? Because you don't have any handler code (`done` method in jQuery) at browser's side.

Comment: the browser doesn't display the "hi" message sent by res.send. now, in my 2nd example it does display it, my entire website html is "removed" and i see "Thanks!"

Answer (score 0):

You may try polyfill "fetch" instead jQuery:

```
function getResponse (url) {
  return fetch(url, {
      method: 'post',
        headers: {
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ time, src })
      })
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log('request succeeded with JSON response', data)
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('request failed', error)
      })
}
```

I think it will look much better. And it can be used on server side.
Docs: https://github.com/github/fetch